# How to aggregate on the same field:value which are specified in query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

So my data in elasticsearch looks like this one whole dict with one person id is equal to one doc and it  contains list of objects like

```
`{
  "dummy_name": "abc",
  "dummy_id": "44850642"
}`
```

which is shown below ,the thing is I am querying on the field `dummy_id` and I am getting result as some no. of matching query results, and I want to aggregate on `dummy_id` field so I'll get no of docs for a specific `dummy_id`, but what happening is I am also getting the buckets of `dummy_id` which are not mentioned in the query its self as person contains list of objects in which  `dummy_id` is present.

```
`{
  "person_id": 1234,
  "Properties": {
    "Property1": [
      {
        "dummy_name": "abc",
        "dummy_id": "44850642"
      },
      {

      },
      {

      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "person_id": 1235,
  .........
}`
```

Query Iam using:

```
`{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Properties.Property1.dummy_id": "453041 23234324 124324 "
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by_concept": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Properties.Property1.dummy_id",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        },
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: I don't understand - Are you querying for dummy_name or dummy_id.
You mentioned on querying on dummy_name and getting wrong dummy_id's, perhaps there are other dummy_id's with those dummy names

Comment: I've update the question accordingly and let me know the question is still clear ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem which is coming is how are you keeping the data.
For eg In this document

```
{
  "person_id": 1234,
  "Properties": {
    "Property1": [
      {
        "dummy_name": "abc",
        "dummy_id": "44850642"
      },
      {
        "dummy_name": "dfg",
        "dummy_id": "876468"
      },
      {

      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The tokens that would be generated in this document would be

- Dummy id tokens - 44850642,876468.This is how data is kept in backend in Lucene

So when you would query for dummy_id:44850642

you would get the document, but aggregations aggregates on terms produced by the documents matching the query

So as a result you would see buckets of 44850642 as well as 876468.

For more information on how elasticsearch keeps data of a list of objects , here is the link - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html